# Как сделать принудительное завершение цикла, если пароль указан верно?

Tags: python, while, break

```
while True:
    name = input('Как тебя зовут: ')
    if name == 'Игорь':
        print('Привет, Игорь!')
        break
    elif name != 'Игорь':
        age = input('Введите свой возраст: ')
        if age >= str(18):
            print('Ты не Игорь, но тоже пойдет...')
            break
        elif age < str(18):
            for password in range(3):
                while True:
                    password = input('Введите пароль: ')
                    if password == str(123):
                            print('Мы тебе доверяем')
                            break
                    else:
                        print('Доступ запрещен.')
                        break
            break
    break
```

Comment: Лучше не используй так много условий и циклов, если можно обойтись без этого. `for password in range(3)` совсем ненужная конструкция.

Answer (score 2):

Можешь использовать флаги, а потом их проверять на корректность.

```py
...
correct = False
while not correct:
    password = input('Введите пароль: ')
    if password == '123':
        correct = True
        print('Мы тебе доверяем')
        break
if correct:
    break
...
```